# Add a wysiwyg editor in custom category attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, category, wysiwyg

I have added a WYSIWYG editor in extension so that one can add a WYSIWYG editor in the attribute. So i added these think in the main.php

```
  array(
        'value' => 'wysiwyg',
        'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('WYSIWYG Editor')
    ),
```

Now what i do for get the WYSIWYG editor in the category.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you wanting to add a wysiwyg editor to one/all category attributes? Maybe if you include the code that you already have this would help us to understand.

Comment: Hey Ranjit, did you have any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The wysiwyg editor is available on the `textarea` type input. So if you are using the installer script to add your attribute for example use these options. Don't forget to append the other options you might need there like `label`.

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'your_attribute', array(
   [...]
   'type' => 'text',
   'input' => 'textarea',
   'wysiwyg_enabled'   => true,
   [...]
));
```